# Passing over values on a SplitPanel and adding for each value a new Label/Textbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, buttonclick

C# and I won't be best friends in near future, but I am trying to do my best :D
What am I trying to do is, that I want to get some Attributes with the corresonding values out of some diagrams and then write it into some windows forms. I though about one SplitPanel. On the left side I wanted to add for every Attribute a Label and on the right side, for the value a Textbox. Normally i guess a label would also do it, but on the second step I want the oppurtunity to change the values, by writing the new value into the Textbox. But thats to far in the future, first i want to get the values into the panel. Getting the values is no problem, but the next step causes me big problems. Additionally I have two Buttons, one for getting the values out of the diagram and one to submit eventually changes. The submitButton is at the moment no sooo relevant.

![valueChanger.jpg][1]

I guess a code tells more than 1000 words, so here is what i have done so far:

```
string Attributes;
string Values;
string tag;
tag = "";
Attributes = "";
Values = "";

foreach (EA.Element theElement in myPackage.Elements)
{
  foreach (EA.Attribute theAttribute in theElement.Attributes)
    {
      Attributes = theAttribute.Name.ToString();
      Values = theAttribute.Default.ToString();
      tag = tag + Attributes + Values + Environment.NewLine;
    }

  /*TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myPackage.Name.ToString() + ".txt");
  writer.WriteLine(tag.ToString());
  writer.Close();*/
  }
```

The part with the Textwriter I isnerted just to check if the Output is right...it is.

Now the Code-behind of the Form:

```
public partial class ValueChanger : Form
{
    public ValueChanger()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new ValueChanger());   
    }
    public void splitContainer1_Panel1_Paint(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs  e)
    {
       Label Alabel = new Label();
       Alabel.Text = Attributes.ToString();
    }

    public void splitContainer1_Panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox Box = new TextBox();
        Box.Text = Values.ToString();
    }

    /*private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }*/

    private void GetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

For the GetButton i tried different alternatives, but didnt get anything to going. Just cant get access to the attributes and values. Its the first time I do anything with windows forms with C#. In general I am pretty new to C#. My problem might be trivial but it made me sweat all afternoon long. I dont expect a full answer with code and everything. About tips and hints I would be very happy.

Comment: Can you please be precise of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in fact simple, every container (like `Panel`) has a property called `Controls`, to show a control as a child of a container, you have to add that control to the container. Here is the simplified version of the code which you may need:

```
private void AddEntry(string attribute, string value){
   Label lbl = new Label {Text=attribute, Dock=DockStyle.Top};
   lbl.Parent = splitContainer1.Panel1;//This is the same to splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
   lbl.BringToFront();

   TextBox txt = new TextBox {Text=value, Dock=DockStyle.Top};
   txt.Parent = splitContainer1.Panel2;
   txt.BringToFront();
   lbl.Height = txt.Height;
}
//I guess you want to add new entry to your splitContainer in this foreach
foreach (EA.Element theElement in myPackage.Elements)
{
  foreach (EA.Attribute theAttribute in theElement.Attributes)
  {
     Attributes = theAttribute.Name.ToString();
     Values = theAttribute.Default.ToString();
     //call the method above
     AddEntry(Attributes, Values);
     tag = tag + Attributes + Values + Environment.NewLine;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will check it, but on the first look it looks good. Brings more light into the shadow :)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code. I added the AddEntry-method into the FormClass and the Rest in the projectClass. I still loop over the single attributes and call the AddEntry-method. But I get the CS0103 error, like the Name "AddEntry" is missing in the actual context. Its logical that this errors occurs, but how can I fix it? Is there any command I need to add?

Comment: @Alika87 what is the exact exception? all the code I posted in my answer should be placed in the same `class`.

Comment: This Problem with the exception I fixed, but now I have to deal with another exception. I will post the code, it would be nice if u could take a quick look at.

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet to comment for clarification.

I think your structure is wrong, you should be having pair of loops inside the GetButton_Click event to loop through the values that you fetch from the source and then put pairs of Labels/TextBoxes in your SPlitContainer.

The paint event can fire on any occasion, so shouldn't be doing anything more that formatting in there.

If you're new to Winforms, you wont know about DataGridView, for this exact scenario, you should learn :)

Comment: thank you for your advice, I will look into DataGridView, I am indeed really new to Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing an Addin for enterprise architect, the code below is part of the main-class:

```
 case "&Change Values":


 string attribute;
 string value;
 attribute = "";
 value = "";

 ChangeValues c = new ChangeValues();

 foreach (EA.Element theElement in myPackage.Elements)
 {
 foreach (EA.Attribute theAttribute in theElement.Attributes)
   {
   attribute = theAttribute.Name.ToString();
   value = theAttribute.Default.ToString();
   c.AddEntry(attribute, value);
   } 
 }

 break;
```

this is the code of the winform:

```
public ChangeValues()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        ChangeValues.ActiveForm.Activate();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new ChangeValues());
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    }

public void AddEntry(string attribute, string value)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label { Text = attribute, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        lbl.Parent = splitContainer1.Panel1;//This is the same to splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        lbl.BringToFront();

        TextBox txt = new TextBox { Text = value, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        txt.Parent = splitContainer1.Panel2;
        txt.BringToFront();
        lbl.Height = txt.Height;
    }

private void ChangeValues_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

When I try to launch the Addin, I get a NullReferenceException. I searched for over an hour, but couldn't find the reason for this exception.

Comment: What is the line at which the `NullReferenceException` is thrown?

Comment: The exception comes from enterprise architect. It tells me in which method the exception is. In this case, its in the case "&Change Values".

Comment: your `ChangeValues()` constructor has something wrong. All the `Application.xxxx` should be placed in the `Main` static method in the `Program.cs` file. Your code should throw a `StackOverflowException` but it looked like that it didn't (because you didn't mention it).

Comment: You are indeed the Kind :D I did what u said and the exception has gone, but the window still don't pop up. All this infos about the windows are so confusing -.-

Comment: The window doesn't pop up because you didn't call `Show()` on the instance `c`. After the `foreaches` and right before `break;` you should call `c.Show();`.

Comment: Hey King, i wanted to thank you for your great help :) It works everything fine. Now I have a little question, I added scrollbars to the Panels of the Splitcontainer. Is there a possibility to have just one Scrollbar, to scroll down both panels paralel?

Comment: you don't need to use scrollbar controls, just set `SplitContainer.Panel1.AutoScroll = SplitContainer.Panel2.AutoScroll = true`. Add **`Scroll`** event handlers for both the panels:`private void splitContainer1_Panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e){splitContainer1.Panel2.VerticalScroll.Value = e.NewValue; }` and `private void splitContainer1_Panel2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e){splitContainer1.Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = e.NewValue; }`

Comment: Thanks King, I managed it to do it on my own yesterday after I asked you. I did it like you said. Thank you for yor help, I appreciate it really much.

Comment: Hey King, sorry to bother you again, but I have another question, you have been a great help for me so far. My Problem: Everything works great so far, the window pops up and i can see all attributes and values. Now I want to be able, to change some values and put them back into the modeldiagram. Exactly the other way around like we did so far.I have big problems to get access to the single labels and Textboxes of the Panels. I wanted to iterate through every field in the panel, check if the value changed and put the value back into the model.

Comment: My question now: how do i get access to the labels/Textboxes? private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { foreach (SplitContainer sc1 in this.Controls.OfType<SplitContainer>()) { }    Thats what I have so far, no matter which way I tried, couldnt get it done. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: All the labels are added to `splitContainer1.Panel1`,so to access the labels you can loop through `splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls`, all the textBoxes are added to `splitContainer1.Panel2`,so to access the textBoxes you can loop through `splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls`. You can specify your labels and textBoxes with unique `Name` or `Tag` (in the `AddEntry()` method) to access them later, for example, you can name one of your `Label` as `LabelAtRow3` then you can access it later by `splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls["LabelAtRow3"]`.The return value is `Control`,so you have to cast it to `Label`

Comment: Hi King, thanks for your help. I tried to realise your suggestion, but I dont get all the labels and textboxes. I just get the last label. I use a foreach-loop to iterate through, but it dont work. This is my code:     foreach (Label theLabels in splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls) { int i = 0; Label lblOut = (Label) splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls[i]; i++; }

Comment: Do I use the Controls wrong? Normally this foreach loop should iterate through every element of the panel1.